# Converting GCP RecognizeResponse to json

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to get JSON response back from GCP speech to text api using java sdk for java in my spring boot application and then pass that on to the angular frontend to get displayed.But the problem is googles doc suggest the reply would be something like
[gcp doc link](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/word-confidence#speech_transcribe_word_level_confidence_beta-java)

```
    {
  "results": [
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "transcript": "how old is the Brooklyn Bridge",
          "confidence": 0.98360395,
          "words": [
            {
              "startTime": "0s",
              "endTime": "0.300s",
              "word": "how",
              "confidence": SOME NUMBER
            },
            ...
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

but when I invoke speechclient.recognize and try to convert it to Json   using GSn library as shown below

```
            Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            ByteString audioBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(data);

            // Builds the sync recognize request
            RecognitionConfig config =
                    RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                            .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
                            .setLanguageCode("en-US")
                            .setEnableWordConfidence(true)
                            .setEnableWordTimeOffsets(true)
                            .build();
            RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder().setContent(audioBytes).build();

            // Performs speech recognition on the audio file
            response = speechClient.recognize(config, audio);
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

            logger.error(gson.toJson(response));

            file.write(gson.toJson(response));

            file.flush();
            file.close();
```

This is whats written in file

```
{
  "results_": [
    {
      "alternatives_": [
        {
          "transcript_": "but what if somebody decides to break it be careful that you keep adequate coverage but look for places to save money baby it\u0027s taking longer to get things squared away then the bankers expected hiring the life for one\u0027s company may win her tax aided retirement income the booth just helpful but inadequate new self to saving Rags or hardly tossed on the two naked bones what it discussion Canyon Sue when the title of this type of song is in question there\u0027s no dying or waxing or gassing need a paperweight maybe personalized known back Quoc Leigh is leather hard place work on a flat surface and smooth out this simplest kind of separate system uses a single self-contained unit to the old shop outage still Holts a good mechanic is usually a bad boss so fingers would go higher in later years so make beautiful chairs cabinets chest doll houses it\u0027s at",
          "confidence_": 0.6881865,
          "words_": [
            {
              "startTime_": {
                "seconds_": 0,
                "nanos_": 0,
                "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                "unknownFields": {
                  "fields": {},
                  "fieldsDescending": {}
                },
                "memoizedSize": -1,
                "memoizedHashCode": 0
              },
              "endTime_": {
                "seconds_": 0,
                "nanos_": 200000000,
                "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                "unknownFields": {
                  "fields": {},
                  "fieldsDescending": {}
                },
                "memoizedSize": -1,
                "memoizedHashCode": 0
              },
              "word_": "but",
              "confidence_": 0.53119344,
              "speakerTag_": 0,
              "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
              "unknownFields": {
                "fields": {},
                "fieldsDescending": {}
              },
              "memoizedSize": -1,
              "memoizedHashCode": 0
            },......
```

All that extra stuff plus '_' at the end was not expected can someone help me with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen to enable **word-by-word** confidence: `setEnableWordConfidence(true)`. See [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/videointelligence/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/videointelligence/v1/model/GoogleCloudVideointelligenceV1SpeechTranscriptionConfig.html#setEnableWordConfidence-java.lang.Boolean-) for the JavaDoc. So this is provided for each word.

If you remove that, or set it to false, you will not see any of those details.

This is different from (i.e. additional to) the confidence of the **overall transcript** - the section you expected to see.

Comment: Thanks for reply.all those extra field i dont mind but the '__' at the end of each word is kind of weird and I did try without word-by-word but still i am getting '_' at the end of words. Although i have found a workaround to this and it has solved my problem but why it adds '_' at the end is a mystery.

Comment: If you don't have a problem with those extra fields, then perhaps you can edit your question to make this clear. You said "All that extra stuff was not expected" - but it sounds as if it's not actually a problem.

Comment: Regarding the underscores you were not expecting to see: Bear in mind that this feature - _and the related documentation_ is all in beta mode. Look at the banner at the top of the documentation page [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/word-confidence). Don't be surprised if the documentation does not exactly sync up with the code/data outputs.